# Best way of new grad getting sponsored for Australian Work Visa

Tags: working-visas, us-citizens, australia

I am in the last stages of obtaining my Masters of Science, am young (24), and have been looking at options of getting my first job abroad, specifically Australia has always been that destination for me. Looking at Australia's immigration site, I feel that being sponsored gives you a much better shot applying for a visa. I am lost at where to start looking for jobs that would fit for me and contact the management to talk about sponsorship. My background is a Masters in Computer Engineering and general electronics.

For now I have set up a account on seek.com.au and browsed a few jobs relating to my field. I have also done general searching on google for mainstream Australian media to expose myself to news and potentially find companies that way. I found in another question a reference to spotjobs.com.

Besides for companies that are global and I know exist (Google, Rolls Royce,etc.) are there any sites that advertise tech startups looking for workers or prominent tech companies in Australia?

This could also be considered a chicken and the egg problem. Employers look for people eligible to already live/work in Australia/have Australian citizenship, but I am in the process of applying after I get sponsored and talking to the companies.

EDIT: Latest developments are that though I have found some jobs an almost perfect fit in my field, they are in defence and require Australian citizenship. Anyone have any success stories for getting a job in non-security clearance, kind of work as an expat?

Comment: I believe that from the employers side, there's quite a bit of work to do to sponsor someone for a visa, so a small startup may not have the time+experience+resources to do that

Comment: @Gagravarr Thinking about it, I agree with you on that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for you is to get a holiday visa and search for a job in a company who has the budget and move to a 457 skilled visa later.

Comment: That idea has indeed already crossed my mind, but it presents an investment on my part, not that I would mind touring Australia but still. Most companies (at least in the USA) list openings online... is the same not true for Australia?